# write .htaccess to make all the files n folders present in a folder to be served on my website when in maintenance mode (403 (forbidden mode))?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I have the following file structure in cPanel

```
web_root_folder_
               |____.neverDelete/_____
               |                     |_____img/logo-30.png
               |                     |_____js/error-page.js
               |                     |_____css/error-page.css
               |
               |____403.shtml
               |
               |____.htaccess
```

I wanted to write `.htaccess` with some code that puts the website in 'maintenance mode'.
So...I wrote `403.shtml` page, which uses external css, javascript and images stored in `.neverDelete` folder.

I wrote the following code in `.htaccess`

```
# The WORKING CODE (Too Long )
Deny From All
<FilesMatch 404-layout.min.css>
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch logo-small-transparent-30.png>
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch error-page.js>
    Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

This code successfully worked. It implemented a `403(forbidden)` for all files except the 3 files (mentioned in `.htaccess` file)

but, I want to make all the files n folders present in `.neverDelete/` to be served on my website when in maintenance mode.

So i visited http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory to get help. I wrote the code in `.htaccess` below that actually gave in a `500(server error)`.

```
# WRONG CODE
Deny From All
<Directory .neverDelete/ >
    Allow From All
</Directory>
```

How can I make all the files n folders present in `.neverDelete/` to be served on my website when in `maintenance mode`.

Comment: _Aside:_ A "403 Forbidden" is not generally considered "maintenance mode" (as this could have a negative effect on SEO). A "503 Service Unavailable" response with an appropriate `Retry-After` header is "maintenance mode".

Comment: thankyou @MrWhite for the useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `.htaccess` file, you can't use a `Directory` tag, since the file itself defines the directory -- the one it is in. For this, you can use the `Allow` and `Deny` directives in the .`htaccess` file without any kind of container.

So if you put a `.htaccess` file to your `.neverDelete/` directory with the contents

```
Allow from all
```

it will make the contents of the directory available.

Comment: `Allow` and `Deny` are strictly deprecated on Apache 2.4 - you should be using the corresponding `Require ...` directives instead (but note that _all_ instances would need to be upgraded, as mixing the 2 authorization modules can produce unexpected results).